# Multiple AudioContext error when playing sounds on element's hover state

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, audiocontext, web-audio-api

I'm trying to play sounds and visualize the frequency (via D3.js) when I'm hovering an item. The problem is that I get this error when I jump from one item to another:

```
main.js:94 Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to construct 'AudioContext': The number of hardware contexts provided (6) is greater than or equal to the maximum bound (6)
```

Here's my code:

```
    $('.item').on('mouseenter', function(){
    itemId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(itemId).trigger("play");

    var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    var audioElement = document.getElementById(itemId);
    var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
    var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

    // Bind our analyser to the media element source.
    audioSrc.connect(analyser);
    audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(50);

    //D3.JS Stuffs here
});
$('.item').on('mouseleave', function(){
    itemId = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('#' + coverId).trigger("pause");
});
```

I've tried a lot of stuff but nothing works, any help would be very very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*AudioContext* should be unique. Try to declare it only once, outside of your `mouseenter` function.

Comment: Already tried that but it throws an error on the createMediaElementSource() and says that the HTMLelement is already bounded :/